# How can I index and query nested arrays in Dexie.js?

Tags: dexie

The docs for [MultiEntry](https://dexie.org/docs/MultiEntry-Index) indexes say any [Indexable Type](https://dexie.org/docs/Indexable-Type) can be used.

Arrays are indexable types. Therefore it should be possible to index arrays of arrays and so on, right?

However, I couldn't find any examples or figure out how to query these.

Basically, what I want is something like:

```js
var db = new Dexie('dbname');

db.version(1).stores({
  books: 'id, author, name, *properties'
});

db.books.put({
  id: 1,
  name: 'Human Action', 
  author: 'Ludwig von Mises',
  properties: [['language', 'english'], ['subject', 'philosophy'], ['subject', 'economics']]
});
```

Then be able to find a book that has an `economics` subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. Each entry in the properties array is an array of two strings - and that inner array itself is indexable and may act as an indexable entry.

So to find all books that has subject economics, do

```
db.books.where({properties: ['subject', 'economics']}).toArray()
```

or the equivalent form:

```
db.books
  .where('properties')
  .equals(['subject', 'economics'])
  .toArray();
```